# WPF hit-testable grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a video player using LibVLCSharp in WPF. Anything rendered above must be done within . I'm working on my own playback controls from scratch and am currently prototyping the hide able playback seeker so it's not always visible. I'm wanting to use MouseMove to decide whether or not to display the grid "PlaybackControls" however the event is only being fired while going over another control that is inside the grid. Changing the background color does fix this issue and allows the entire grid to be hit-testable though making the background color transparent does not fire the event. I'm still a bit new to xaml as I've finally switched from WinForms so I apologize if this is an obvious issue but I've been searching all over google for a fix.

```
<Window x:Class="OnePacer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vlc="clr-namespace:LibVLCSharp.WPF;assembly=LibVLCSharp.WPF"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OnePacer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Black"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="750">

<Grid>
    <vlc:VideoView x:Name="videoView">
        <Grid PreviewMouseMove="videoView_PreviewMouseMove" Background="Transparent">
            <Grid x:Name="PlaybackControls" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Slider Maximum="100" Margin="15 0 15 35" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="Seeker" Style="{DynamicResource Horizontal_Slider}" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Thumb.DragStarted="Seeker_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="Seeker_DragCompleted" ValueChanged="Seeker_ValueChanged"/>
                <Button Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </vlc:VideoView>
</Grid>
```

EDIT

While setting the background to transparent wont work setting it to a low transparent color works (#01FFFFFF) I'm still open to hearing other fixes as there may be a better solution.

Comment: in these cases i always use opacity=0.01 on that control, then when mouseover i set it back to 1. Human eye cant see that kind opacity, but machine can :). Hope it helps.

Comment: @DumidorDumbleplex This is something I also tried however it also doesn't fire the event.

Comment: Well it doesn't fire because the background cant be transparent, then it don't matter if opacity is set or not.

Comment: Does the `Grid` fill your `VideoView`? What if you set the `Background` of the latter?

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
  <Grid Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseMove="videoView_PreviewMouseMove" >
    <vlc:VideoView x:Name="videoView">
        <Grid >
            <Grid x:Name="PlaybackControls" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Slider Maximum="100" Margin="15 0 15 35" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="Seeker" Style="{DynamicResource Horizontal_Slider}" IsMoveToPointEnabled="True" Thumb.DragStarted="Seeker_DragStarted" Thumb.DragCompleted="Seeker_DragCompleted" ValueChanged="Seeker_ValueChanged"/>
                <Button Width="20" Height="20" Margin="5 0 0 5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </vlc:VideoView>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Anything rendered above VideoView must be done inside it's control as stated in the question.

Comment: LibVLCSharp for WPF has an airspace issue, you can read about it here under the "WPF" in their [repository](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/3.x/docs/getting_started.md)

Comment: I found a simple solution by changing the background to a nearly transparent color, but I'm still open to better solutions.

Comment: @Justin Can u please try the last edit?